# Turn on My Computer after reconnecting the power cable witout having to touch the power button

Tags: power-supply, power

Upon reconnecting the power cable to the computer without having to touch the power button is turned. what can I do? Is my Power Supply damage?

Comment: That’s not unusual. Some motherboards will automatically turn on when you connect the power. You should be able to turn it off and back on as normal without problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you turn on the Computer, touch <kbd>Delete</kbd> Key or press any key that takes you into the BIOS (<kbd>Del</kbd>/<kbd>F2</kbd>) and go to the BIOS. Find the **Power Management** part and there may be ab option similar to the `AC Back Function` or `Restore on AC Power Loss`. When you enter one of these, you can see 3 options about Soft-Off (Power-Off), Full-On (Power-On) and Memory (Last State). Select Soft-Off, and your system is set probably on the Full-On.

[image: Restore on AC Power Loss]

Comment: Note that the key used to bring up the BIOS varies.

Comment: @IsaacRabinovitch I Changed that. Thanks for your Hint.

Comment: don't forget F10 and a few others....http://pcsupport.about.com/od/fixtheproblem/a/biosaccess_bios.htm

Comment: I hold delete and change it like your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bios setting.  Some bioses allow the state after power failure to be set.  When I can, I set the system to power on when power is restored.  This allow the system to recover from a power failure automatically.